# Return text in .R script as a string

Tags: r, string

This may be a strange request, and there is not much I can do to actually show an example. Though I will try my hardest. Let's say I have an R script, such as a simple one that looks like this:

```
library(lubridate)
setwd("")
df=read.csv("...")
df=df[df$month != "" & !is.na(df$month),]
colnames(df)[3]="metric"
```

Is there now a way, to return a string which contains the actual text in my script? Or a creative way to save the information and read it back into the environment. For instance, I would like to create a string variable which is equal to:

```
"
library(lubridate)
setwd("")
df=read.csv("...")
df=df[df$month != "" & !is.na(df$month),]
colnames(df)[3]="metric""
```

Comment: Not sure what you want, but assuming your script is already saved in a file, you can read it as text using `readLines('script.r')`. If you want to run the script inside another session without opening the file, you can use `source('script.r')`.

Comment: Thanks! Simple solution that I should have known, but was helpful to do what I needed

Answer (score 1):

This just requires a quick google search.

- [how to replace single backslash in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424382/how-to-replace-single-backslash-in-r)
- [Which function should I use to read unstructured text file into R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19714673/which-function-should-i-use-to-read-unstructured-text-file-into-r)

Assuming that you have a text file named test.txt

```
tt <- readLines("test.txt")
gsub("\\\"","\'",tt)
```

Results:

```
> gsub("\\\"","\'",tt)
[1] "'"                                        
[2] "library(lubridate)"                       
[3] "setwd('')"                                
[4] "df=read.csv('...')"                       
[5] "df=df[df$month != '' & !is.na(df$month),]"
[6] "colnames(df)[3]='metric'"
```

But...

- I changed "" to ''...for example look at `setwd`
- I would be careful with the gsub part. By that I mean you have to be
  aware of what your text file contains. If a text file contains back
  slashes: "\\path\\to\\file" then the code will fail

Comment: I think you meant to have colnames(df)[3]="metric"